# NodeJS with Apache and directory listing

Tags: node.js, apache

I am trying to migrate my NodeJS app which works fine from a dedicated server running Nginx to another running Apache2.

Here is my Nginx configuration file

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  root /home/user/myapp;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://example.com:9000;
  }

  location /logs {
    autoindex on;
  }
}
```

and here is my Apache2 configuration file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/user/myapp

ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location />
  ProxyPass http://example.com:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse http://example.com:9000/
</Location>

<Directory /home/user/myapp/logs>
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The NodeJS app works on both http server but I am only able to get the listing directory `http://example.com/logs` with Nginx but not with Apache2 where NodeJS responds

```
Cannot GET /logs/
```

Is something missing in the Apache2 configuration file? Obviously every Apache2 mod are enabled `proxy_http` `proxy` and `autoindex`.

Comment: You have 2 location blocks in your nginx config, but only one in the Apache config.

Comment: Replacing `Directory` by `Location` does not change anything `Cannot GET /logs/`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean remove the `<Directory>`, I mean add `<Location /logs><Location>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `ProxyPass /logs !` works!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/user/myapp
ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /logs !

<Location />
    ProxyPass http://example.com:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://example.com:9000/
</Location>

<Directory /home/user/myapp/logs>
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```